# Slick 3 for scala update query not functioning

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

First of I would like to state that I am new to slick and am using version 3.1.1 . I been reading the manual but i am having trouble getting my query to work. Either something is wrong with my connection string or something is wrong with my Slick code. I got my config from here http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/database.html and my update example from here bottom of page http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html . Ok so here is my code

**Application Config.**

```
mydb= {
  dataSourceClass = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
  properties = {
    databaseName = "Jsmith"
    user = "postgres"
    password = "unique"
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

**My Controller**  -- Database table is called - relations

```
package controllers
import play.api.mvc._
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._

class Application extends Controller {

  class relations(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int,Int,Int)](tag, "relations") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
    def me = column[Int]("me")
    def following = column[Int]("following")
    def * = (id,me,following)

  }

  val profiles = TableQuery[relations]

  val db = Database.forConfig("mydb")


  try {
    // ...
  } finally db.close()




  def index = Action {

    val q = for { p <- profiles if p.id === 2 } yield p.following
    val updateAction = q.update(322)
    val invoker = q.updateStatement
    Ok()
  }

}
```

What could be wrong with my code above ? I have a separate project that uses plain JDBC and this configuration works perfectly for it

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Jsmith"
db.default.user="postgres"
db.default.password="unique"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not run your action yet. `db.run(updateAction)` executes your query respectively your action on a database (untested):

```
def index = Action.async {
  val q = for { p <- profiles if p.id === 2 } yield p.following
  val updateAction = q.update(322)

  val db = Database.forConfig("mydb")
  db.run(updateAction).map(_ => Ok())
}
```

`db.run()` returns a `Future` which will be eventually completed. It is then simply mapped to a `Result` in play.

`q.updateStatement` on the other hand just generates a sql statement. This can be useful while debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Look the code from my project:

```
def updateStatus(username: String, password: String, status: Boolean): Future[Boolean] = {
  db.run(
    (for {
      user <- Users if user.username === username
    } yield {
      user
    }).map(_.online).update(status)
  }
```